# List nearby wifi networks on iOS with a Cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm writing a cross-platform mobile app with Cordova CLI (not PhoneGap) to control an IoT device. How do I display a list of nearby Wifi networks so that the user can select it and connect to it?

I've tried WifiWizard and [WifiWizard2](https://github.com/tripflex/WifiWizard2) but they seem to have limited support for iOS. And [Cordova's core Connection plugin](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/phonegap1.9/cordova_connection_connection.md.html) can only show whether the user is connected to wifi, cellular, or nothing.

I've also found some wifi related Cordova plugins that seem to have lost support for iOS, such as [NativeSettingsOpener](https://github.com/bq/bitbloq-communication-app/tree/master/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.nativesettingsopener).

I've tried this basic WifiWizard2 function:

```
    WifiWizard2.getConnectedSSID().then(function(network) {
          alert(network);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          alert('oops: ', error);
        });
```

It correctly alerts me that I'm not connected to a network when I run it on localhost on my browser.

I'd expect it to work on iOS too. But when I have this function run on iOS after compiling it for iOS with Cordova, it gives me neither the network nor an error.

Comment: You can't do that from within an app on iOS unless the the device supports Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC), which is licensed under the MFi program.  You will need to instruct the user to open iOS preferences and connect manually to the correct WiFi network.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the scan function asynchronously. Here's an example using ionic and Cordova:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var WifiWizard2: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

    results = [];
    info_txt = "";

    async getNetworks() {
        this.info_txt = "loading...";
        try {
            let results = await WifiWizard2.scan();
            this.results = results;
            this.info_txt = "";
        } catch (error) {
            this.info_txt = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Full example on my own website is here https://www.tonyfox.co.uk/posts/using-wifiwizard2-with-ionic/

Comment: Please note that it is required to *explicitly* disclose any affiliation you may have with products or websites you recommend/link to, otherwise the posts are likely to be deleted as spam.

Comment: Sorry @TylerH, didn't release, I've updated the answer again to mention this

Comment: Please note that declare var could be replace by import in typescript, and it's strongly discouraged to use type any

Comment: Can you add an example code for connect and disconnect the wifi?

Comment: @TonyFox, this plugin scan method throwing below error:
WifiWizard2 scan WifiWizard21044267574 ["options": [<null>]]
  [error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Not supported

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay wifi scan api is not available on ios platform

Comment: @sumesh have you tried on iOS? can you please share any links or info on how to make it work on iOS? I just want to connect to existing network but it seem we also need to to native ios configuration like adding entitlement etc